# Can't set JAVA_HOME on Catalina

Tags: java, bash, macos, java-home

I use Catalina. I created the `.bash_profile` file and edited it.

I wrote `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` in this file and typed `source ~/.bash_profile`, after that typed `echo $JAVA_HOME` and showed the path but when I reopen the terminal and type `echo $JAVA_HOME`, doesn't show the path again.

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have a `.bashrc` file?

Comment: How can I check it? Is that must be under of "ls -al" command?

Comment: try this on terminal `vi ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I only have these files. https://imgur.com/a/LINYJHH

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`, and not `zsh`? (That's a rhetorical question: you are almost certainly using `zsh`, which is the default login shell in Catalina and ignores `.bash_profile`. Use `.zprofile` instead, creating it if necessary.)

Comment: I am not sure because I just wanted to install Java JDK with Java Home and watched some videos from YouTube. I did the steps to install it and that was the first seeing the word "bash". I am new on the MacOS too, so I actually don't understand what you talk about. I mean like zsh or bash words. I just want to install this correctly. Can you explain to me basically, please?

Comment: I have solved that with creating .zprofile and copying the quote to it. @chepner Thanks.

Comment: There are several different shells on unix, and both the image you provided and the fact that Macs default to zsh (the Z shell) indicate that you are using zsh as your shell, not bash (the Bourne Again Shell).

Comment: Youtube's all video creators about Java Home on MacOS were use bash, do you think why? I use Mac about 2 months and zsh default on me. Why they have changed that?

Comment: Apple has (apparently for licensing reasons) never included `bash` 4 or later with macOS, shipping only the very old 3.2 version. Each release, though, has included a recent version of `zsh`, and this seems to be the first step towards moving away from `bash` altogether. Note that you always have the option of installing a newer version of `bash` yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New user accounts in Catalina default to using `zsh`, not `bash`. You need to set your environment in `~/.zprofile`, not `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: ... Or set your shell to `bash` and not `zsh`!

Comment: That means either using a shell which is a decade out of date, or installing a new version of `bash` yourself. `zsh` is already installed, and for the casual user, much closer to modern versions of `bash` than `bash` 3.2 is.

Comment: can someone direct me how to do this.
set java_home by writing into ~/.zprofile

Comment: also this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XjkaN8psp0, helped me understand how to edit .zshrc file and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bash_profile` is executed at the time of login. If you just log out and login again, it should be fine. 
For interactive non-login shells `.bash_rc` is used.

Comment: adding $JAVA_HOME to `.bashrc` should work in this case.

Comment: I checked and I don't have .bashrc file. How can I solve this problem and how can I add $JAVE_HOME to .bashrc like you said. I have these files. https://imgur.com/a/LINYJHH

Comment: @Baris It's `.bashrc`, not `bashrc`. If you don't have it, how can you solve this problem? Simple. Create it.