# Can't set JAVA_HOME dynamically on macOS Catalina

Tags: java, bash, macos, java-home

tl,dr;
Doing `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14)` once `JAVA_HOME` was already set won't change active java

---

Steps

1. set `JAVA_HOME` first (for example with `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)`):

```
$ echo ${JAVA_HOME}
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)
```

2. Try to set it to different version (for example `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14)`) - it still uses previously set `java` (even though `JAVA_HOME` was updated):

```
$ echo ${JAVA_HOME}
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home

$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)
```

I'm not sure why it's not working now - it was working just fine a while back (I'd say 2-3 months ago)

There is a seemingly similar topic ([Can't set JAVA_HOME on Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012746/cant-set-java-home-on-catalina)) but it boils down to different shell. In my case I'm using same shell - bash from brew:

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I don't know much about macos, but is there an equivalent to the window's `PATH` env variable in order to find the `java` command?

Comment: There is, but previously it was updated automatically to reflect updated `JAVA_HOME` (which was very handy if you wanted to switch quickly active `java` version in the current shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally managed to solve the issue. As other have pointed out, everything has to do with `PATH` variable. And I indeed had `JAVA_HOME/bin` in there… which causes the problem. Today during an update I notice that [`openjdk` brew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openjdk.rb#L14) had this comment:

```
keg_only "it shadows the macOS `java` wrapper"
```

And things immediately "clicked". After searching a bit I found [Why isn't java wrapper not picking up the right version specified in JAVA_HOME on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61646049/why-isnt-java-wrapper-not-picking-up-the-right-version-specified-in-java-home-o) which confirmed the issue. By including `JAVA_HOME` in the `PATH` in my `.profile` file I was breaking native macOS functionality of it's `java` wrapper, which selects active `java` version based on currently set `JAVA_HOME`.

This is my example session (from opening the shell and having `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)` in the `.profile` file) -- I have default from the profile, then I set explicitly `JAVA_HOME` and it switches `java` version on the fly:

```sh
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)

$ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14)

$ java -version
openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.2+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.2+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems update `JAVA_HOME` is not getting reflected in `PATH` variable.

So, please update PATH variable also and keep the updated `JAVA_HOME` as the first element in the export `PATH` command

Comment: I have `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` in my `.profile` file. It seems that currently PATH is set for each shell instance. Before it was more "dynamic" and changing only `JAVA_HOME` was also reflected in `PATH`.

Comment: So if you execute `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` in the shell and then try `java -version` is it working as expected

Comment: somewhat, but in that case I end up with paths to both versions in `PATH`

Comment: I think if you add  following lines in   `.profile` file  it should work  `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14)) `     `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: I have them! And setting java itself works just fine. What I try to achieve is to be able to dynamically switch java version *afterwards*. I.e. I open new shell, have java11 (as per profile) but want to switch to java14. Previously it was enough to switch JAVA_HOME and point to java14. Now it doesn't work and I have to edit my profile file and source it or open new session and then revert the change.